# Migrating to jdk 7 and jwsdp 2 giving cannot find symbol XmlAccessType

Tags: jaxb

I am migrating a legacy project from java 1.4 ,jwsdp 1.3 to java 7 and jwsdp 2.
I found jdk7 has jwsdp 2 included . So in the build xml I am using jdk7 xjc.exe for generating the stubs . The problem that I am getting is the stubs are getting generated but after that when I am compiling the java classes I am 
getting error like ...

```
cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : class XmlAccessType
    [javac] location: package javax.xml.bind.annotation
    [javac] import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
```

I have deleted all the old jwsdp jars from class path and I have no xjc related jar in the classpath .Please suggest what I need to do to get a successful build .
Thanks

Comment: please share the code that is generating the error.  From this, all we can tell you is that you're missing a jar/class on your classpath

Comment: Thanks a million for the kind response .I am running the ant script .Do you want me share the build.xml ? I have removed all jaxb related jar from classpath and I didn't install the jwsdp 2 separately in my local box .

Comment: Now facing a new issue I am not getting the above compilation issue but the jaxb.properties is not generating by xjc compiler . Need help badly .

Comment: Perhaps I can help you solve your own problem:  You said `I have removed all jaxb related jar from classpath`.  The error you're getting states `cannot find symbol ...`  Looks to me like you removed the jar that contains the definition of XmlAccessType